# How to use xml content as a pattern to get file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I would like to get a file from unknown folder. I dont know where the place of those file. The file name is in the childnodes of my xml file. I tried this script, but once I want to get the file, it show all the file in that folder, not only the file that I already specify which is xml childnodes.

```
[xml]$Xml_File = Get-Content -Path "D:\Data\pattern.xml"
$Pattern = $Xml_File.Header.FileName.ChildNodes | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
$Pattern | ForEach-Object {
        Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Folder\*"
}
```

This is the `$Pattern` looks like:

```
20191_601_AS.bto
20191_601_M1.bto
20191_601_N2.bto
```

Raw XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Header>
        <FileName>
           <file1>20191_601_AS.bto</file1>
           <file2>20191_601_M1.bto</file2>
           <file3>20191_601_N2.bto</file3>
        </FileName>
    </Header>
```

Comment: Maybe adding `-filter $_` to your `get-childitem` will help. Piping to `foreach-object` does not automatically pipe a value into commands within the script block

Comment: Can you post an example of your pattern.xml, and the expected output from the script?

Comment: hi @AdminOfThings I already try -filter, but it does not work

Comment: @mclayton I already post the pattern of the xml above `This is the $Pattern looks like:

20191_601_AS.bto
20191_601_M1.bto
20191_601_N2.bto`

Comment: I meant the raw xml file. The one you’ve called “D:\Data\pattern.xml”.

Comment: I will post the raw xml above